# (Proof Updated, Verification in Need) Show that $(s,t)\mapsto t\wedge s$ for $s,t\geq 0$ and $(s,t)\mapsto e^{-|t-s|}$ are positive semi-definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, operator-theory, positive-semidefinite

We say a positive symmetric $n\times n$ matrix $M$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$ is semi-definite if $v^{\intercal}Mv\geq 0$ for all nonzero $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

We say a function $f:\mathbb{T}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to be positive semi-definite if $\Big(f(t_k, t_j)\Big)_{k,j=1}^n$ is a positive semi-definite matrix for all $(t_k)_{k=1}^n\in\mathbb{T}^n$

With this definition, I am working on an exercise asking me to show

> $(1)$ the function $f:(s,t)\mapsto t\wedge s$ defined for $s,t\geq 0$ is positive semi-definite;
>
> $(2)$ the function $c:(s,t)\mapsto e^{-|t-s|}$ is positive semi-definite.

For the first one, I tried to use the fact that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}}\mathbb{1}_{[0,t]}\mathbb{1}_{[0,s]} \,d\mu = t\wedge s,$$ so that each term in the matrix is of the form $b_{i,j}:=f(t_i,t_j)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}}\mathbb{1}_{[0,t_{j}]} \mathbb{1}_{[0,t_{}} \, d\mu$, for $t,j=1,\cdots,n$.

Let $v=(v_1,\ldots, v_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then $$v^{\intercal} Mv=a_1 \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_{i,1}+a_2\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_{i,2} + a_3 \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_{i,3}+\cdots+a_n \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_{i,n}.$$

**But then I don't know what to do next..**

For the second one, the exercise gives an hint: using an auxiliary Hilbert space $H$ and a $h_t\in H$ such that $\langle h_t, h_s\rangle=c(s,t)\ldots$ I don't really know how to use this hint...

I really need an answer with some details, since this is an exercise in Stochastic Process, instead of functional analysis and so forth, so I don't have enough background of this...

Thank you so much!

---

**Edit 1: (Proof of the first one)**

Following **MaoWao**'s suggestion, I think I proved the first one.

Firstly let me claim that if $H$ is a Hilbert space, then its corresponding inner product $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle_H:H\times H\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is positive semi-definite.

Indeed, we have for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $x_1,\ldots, x_n \in H$ and $c_1,\ldots, c_n \in\mathbb{R}$ that $$\sum_{i,j=1}^n c_i c_j \langle x_i,x_j\rangle_H = \left<\sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i,\sum_{j=1}^n c_j x_j \right>_H =\Big\|\sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i\Big\|_H^2\geq 0.$$

In fact, the above result also holds for pre-Hilbert space, since the notion of completeness was not involved in the above argument.

Thus, we only need to find a specific (pre-)Hilbert Space $H$ and a $h_{t}\in H$ such that $\langle h_t, h_s\rangle_H = t\wedge s$.

But this is easy, let's consider $H:=L^2(\mathbb{R}_{+})$, and $h_t:=\mathbb{1}_{[0,t]}$. It is clear that $h_t\in H$, and for any $t,s\geq 0$, we have $$\langle h_t, h_s\rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}_{+})} = \int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}}\mathbb{1}_{[0,t]} \mathbb{1}_{[0,s]} \, d\mu=t\wedge s,$$ and thus we are done.

---

**Edit 2: (Proof of the second one)**

I've searched all over the places. The function in $(2)$ is Abel kernel, but it is rarely discussed since Abel kernel is closely related to Poisson kernel, and most of the discussions are on the latter.

Later, I found a really close one: the Gaussian kernel and here is a link about the proof of Gaussian kernel is really a kernel. That is, it is positive semidefinite.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35634/how-to-prove-that-the-radial-basis-function-is-a-kernel

In this link, one answer used the characteristic function. This greatly inspired me. I also found a characteristic function, which is the one for Cauchy distribution.

Below is the proof:

Recall the Cauchy Distribution $(x_{0},\gamma)$ with $\gamma>0$ has the characteristic function $$\varphi(t)=e^{ix_{0}t-\gamma|t|}.$$

Using this, we can write $c(s,t)=h(s-t)$ where $h(t):=e^{-|t|}=\mathbb{E}e^{itZ}$ is the characteristic function of a random variable $Z$ with Cauchy $(0,1)$ distribution.

Then for real numbers $x_{1},\cdots, x_{n}$ and $a_{1},\cdots, a_{n}$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j,k=1}^{n}a_{j}a_{k}h(x_{j}-x_{k})&=\sum_{j,k=1}^{n}a_{j}a_{k}\mathbb{E}e^{i(x_{j}-x_{k})Z}\\
&=\mathbb{E}\Big(\sum_{j,k=1}^{n}a_{j}e^{ix_{j}Z}a_{k}e^{-ix_{k}Z}\Big)\\
&=\mathbb{E}\Big(\Big|\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}e^{ix_{j}Z}\Big|^{2}\Big)\geq 0.
\end{align*}

Thus, $c$ is positive semi-definite.

**It seems that I did not use the hint at all for part $(2)$, so I believe there must be another way.**

**I do need someone to check if my proof in the edit 1 and edit 2 is correct. I am gonna open a bounty in 19 hours later, for proof checking and possible new proof. Thank you!**

Comment: Is $t \wedge s = \min\left\{t,s\right\}$ ? This isn't the most standard notation. And what is $\mathbb T$ ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg yes, it is. $\mathbb{T}$ is some index set, for instance, $\mathbb{R}_{+}$

Comment: @darijgrinberg I am really sorry about the notation... this exercise is from stochastic process, so it is with the notation in probability theory somehow...

Comment: To you already know (and understand) that for a pre-Hilbert space $H$ and elements $h_1,\dots,h_n\in H$ the matrix $(\langle h_j,h_k\rangle)_{j,k}$ is positive semi-definite? You can also use this hint for (1), and you already found the $h_j$ and almost found the Hilbert space $H$.

Comment: For (2) you can also use Bochner's theorem if you are familiar with it.

Comment: @MaoWao By pre-Hilber space, you mean inner product space? and you are saying for such a space, the matrix is already positive semi-definite? and for $(1)$, the Hilbert space is just $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$? am I correct? Thanks for pointing out a theorem for $(2)$, I am not really familiar with it but I will check it out.

Comment: Yes, the Hilbert space for (1) is just $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (or $L^2(\mathbb{R}_+)$, if you like). I think it would be a good exercise to prove that this matrix is always positive semi-definite to use the hint. Btw, Bochner's theorem can also be reduced to this hint.

Comment: @MaoWao I will follow your hint and post an edit. (after that would you mind taking a look at it to see if I am correct?) Thank you so much!

Comment: @MaoWao Hi! I just edited the post to update my proof of the first one, would you mind telling if  my proof is correct? Thank you! (I will be working the second one)

Comment: Proper notation is not $<x_i,x_j>=\cdots,$ but $\langle x_i, x_j \rangle = \cdots. $ I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelHardy oh! okay... yes I should use $\langle, \rangle$

Comment: @MichaelHardy so my proof in the edit is correct?...

Comment: This looks fine to me. Your proof that the characteristic function of a probability measure is positive semi-definite uses the hint (you take the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{P})$ and $h_t=\exp(it\cdot)$), so maybe that was the intention.

Comment: Btw, it would probably work better if you put your edits into an answer, because that's what they are (and a good one, I think).

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you so much!! And Thank you for your comments about the equivalence between my proof and the hint. I will definitely answer my own equation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **MaoWao** suggested, I am gonna post my own proof here.

---

*Proof of (1):*

Firstly let me claim that if $H$ is a Hilbert space, then its corresponding inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle_{H}:H\times H\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is positive semi-definite.

Indeed, we have for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $x_{1},\cdots, x_{n}\in H$ and $c_{1},\cdots, c_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$ that $$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}c_{i}c_{j}\langle x_{i}, x_{j}\rangle_{H}=\Big<\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}x_{i},\sum_{j=1}^{n}c_{j}x_{j}\Big>_{H}=\Big\|\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}x_{i}\Big\|_{H}^{2}\geq 0.$$

In fact, the above result also holds for pre-Hilbert space, since the notion of completeness was not involved in the above argument.

Thus, we only need to find a specific (pre-)Hilbert Space $H$ and a $h_{t}\in H$ such that $\langle h_{t}, h_{s}\rangle_{H}=t\wedge s$.

But this is immediate. Let's consider $H:=L^{2}(\mathbb{R}_{+})$, and $h_{t}:=\mathbb{1}_{[0,t]}$. It is clear that $h_{t}\in H$, and for any $t,s\geq 0$, we have $$\langle h_{t}, h_{s}\rangle_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}_{+})}=\int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}}\mathbb{1}_{[0,t]}\mathbb{1}_{[0,s]}d\mu=t\wedge s,$$ and thus we are done.

---

*Proof of $(2)$:*

Recall the Cauchy Distribution $(x_{0},\gamma)$ with $\gamma>0$ has the characteristic function $$\varphi(t)=e^{ix_{0}t-\gamma|t|}.$$

Using this, we can write $c(s,t)=h(s-t)$ where $h(t):=e^{-|t|}=\mathbb{E}e^{itZ}$ is the characteristic function of a random variable $Z$ with Cauchy $(0,1)$ distribution.

Then for real numbers $x_{1},\cdots, x_{n}$ and $a_{1},\cdots, a_{n}$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j,k=1}^{n}a_{j}a_{k}h(x_{j}-x_{k})&=\sum_{j,k=1}^{n}a_{j}a_{k}\mathbb{E}e^{i(x_{j}-x_{k})Z}\\
&=\mathbb{E}\Big(\sum_{j,k=1}^{n}a_{j}e^{ix_{j}Z}a_{k}e^{-ix_{k}Z}\Big)\\
&=\mathbb{E}\Big(\Big|\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}e^{ix_{j}Z}\Big|^{2}\Big)\geq 0.
\end{align*}

Thus, $c$ is positive semi-definite.

---

Also, as **MaoWao** pointed out, the proof of $(2)$ can be equivalently written into something similar to what we did in the $(1)$, by taking the Hilbert space $L^{2}(\mathbb{P})$ and $h_{t}=\exp(it\cdot)$

I am really grateful to the help, suggestion and proof verification from **MaoWao**. I'd like also to express my appreciation to **Michael Hardy**, for the discussion and help.

Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 1):

This will be a partial answer.

The standard Wiener process $\{B(t)\}_{t\,\ge\,0},$ also called the standard Brownian motion, assigns to each $t\ge0$ a random variable $B(t)$ in such a way that every increment $B(t)-B(s)$ for $0\le s\le t$ is distributed as $\operatorname N(0,t-s)$ (the standard normal distribution with expected value $0$ and variance $t-s,$ so standard deviation $\sqrt{t-s},$ and for **pairwise disjoint** intervals $(s_i,t_i),$ $i=1,\ldots,n,$ with $0\le s_i\le t_i,$ the increments $B(t_i) - B(s_i)$ are **independent** random variables.

Then for $0\le s\le t$ one can show that
$$
\operatorname{cov}(B(s), B(t)) = s = s\wedge t.
$$
That is done by writing
$$
\operatorname{cov}\Big(B(s), \Big(B(t) - B(s)\Big) + B(s)\Big)
$$
and then using the independence of $B(t) - B(s)$ and $B(s).$

Since all the entries in the matrix of covariances of $B(t_1),\ldots, B(t_n)$ are of the form $t_i\wedge t_j,$ and since every matrix of covariances is positive-semi-definite, the function $(s,t)\mapsto s\wedge t$ must be positive-semi-definite.

Comment: I think the (implicit) purpose of this exercise is to use the fact that $s\wedge t$ is positive semidefinite to show the covariance matrix of Wiener process is positive semi definite. (since we can construct Gaussian process, especially Wiener process, using Hilbert space, and we define such a function, then we want to show the function is positive semi definite.)

Comment: @JacobsonRadical : That seems weird. It is trivial to show that every matrix of covariances is positive-semi-definite. Suppose $X$ is a random vector taking values in $\mathbb R^{n\times1}$ and has expected value $0\in\mathbb R^{n\times1}.$ Let $M$ be the matrix of covariances among the entries in $X.$ Then for any row vector $a\in\mathbb R^{1\times n},$ one has $aMa^\top = a\operatorname E( X X^\top) a^\top = \operatorname E( (aX)(aX)^\top) = \operatorname{var}(aX) \ge 0. \qquad$

Comment: well... you are right... I do agree with your proof.. by the way, do you know if there is anything wrong with my proof?...

Comment: Was it also the part of the purpose to show that the same thing about some other specified random process by using the fact that $(s,t)\mapsto e^{-|s-t|} $ are the covariances? What process was that?

Comment: I think this is called Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, the Gaussian process with $0$ mean and covariance as this function.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical : I suspected that's the one, but I have other things to attend to. Remind me tomorrow, if I don't get back here by then....

Comment: Yes I will definitely keep working on this exercise. (so my proof in the edit is not correct?... okay...)

Comment: I proved the second one. would you mind having a check if my proofs in Edit1  and Edit 2 are correct? I am gonna open a bounty for you :) Thank you so much!

Comment: The covariance is a semi-inner product on the space of all random variables with finite variance (on a given probability space), so this can also be seen as an application of the hint.

Comment: @MaoWao Yes I just learned today that if covariance is finite then the covariance function is automatically semi-definite. Thanks for pointing this out in advance!

Comment: Thank you Hardy for your suggestion and help. I am gonna accept your answer and I will also post a proof by answering my own post (which is already in my edits), as suggested by MaoWao.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical : I haven't yet sufficiently digested your proofs to be sure of anything about them yet.